# Cannot enable 3D acceleration on virtualbox

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox  Version 5.0.40_Ubuntu r115130 on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit.

I need to enable the 3D acceleration to play Age of Empires III, but the option is disabled. How can I enable it?

[image]

Comment: Does your host system have that option?

Comment: I don't know. I tried Windows XP professional. Does it depend to the OS that I install?

Comment: Is the guest live while your doing this?

Comment: Yes it does your host must have it for the guest to use it and do you have guest additions installed on the VBox machine?

Comment: @George, apparently when I turn off wondows, I can enable the option!

Comment: Please look at this article: https://software.grok.lsu.edu/article.aspx?articleid=14125

Comment: Yes the guest must be turned off to enable it, remember guest use the facilities of host!

Comment: Great! Answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Answer added glad that resolved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use 3D Acceleration in Virtualbox guest OS several things are required:

1. Host must have or support 3D, which should be turned on
2. If host has to enable one must first turn off the guest to access the option in the VBox Machine settings for that guest OS.

Except:

> VirtualBox provides experimental 3D hardware support for Windows, Linux, and Solaris Guest Additions. This feature provides support for 3D applications in the VM that uses OpenGL or DirectX 8/9 programming interfaces. VirtualBox will try to use the 3D hardware of the host as opposed to emulating via software. Performance and efficiency is increased when VirtualBox does this. Windows, Mac, Solaris, and Linux are all supported hosts for this feature (given that the host OS can actually utilize the accelerated 3D hardware).
>
> 3D acceleration is accessible only by certain guests of Windows, Linux, and Solaris:
>
> Windows guests-Support is limited to 32-bit editions of XP and Vista
>   OpenGL on Linux-Requires kernel 2.6.27 and later as well as X.org server version 1.5 and later. Fedora 10 and Ubuntu 8.10 have been verified to be in good working condition.
>   OpenGL on Solaris-Requires X.org server version 1.5 and later
>
> NOTE: Guest Additions also must be installed. 3D acceleration must be manually enabled in the virtual machine settings. m3D support is disabled by default.

See here for more information:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-3d

https://software.grok.lsu.edu/article.aspx?articleid=14125

Comment: Does that mean that 3D ist just available in WindowsXP-32bit and not for example in Win10-64bit even though this option is checkable in the Win10-virtual machine?